# Windows 7: My notepad files disappeared and I cannot find them

Tags: windows-7, notepad

So I was doing some work on notepad and I wanted to open the files and they simply disappeared! I looked for them everywhere! I forgot where I saved them I looked up the file name but they would not come up... Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Windows Explorer, click on your Local Disk C: drive. Then in the Search area at the top right, search for *.txt

This will find any notepad file on your computer.

Comment: I did but they would still not show up... I am sure I saved them

Comment: If they aren't found by searching and C: is the only drive in your computer, then unfortunately it would seem they have been deleted. I assume you also checked the Recycle Bin?